# Basic Excel Quiz [Need Help]

Tags: excel

```
State Abr.       State                 Correct/Incorrect \\
AK                   Alaska               Correct \\
AR.                  Arkansas.         Correct \\
AZ.                  Arizone.            Incorrect \\
PA.                                             Incorrect \\
WY.                                            Incorrect\\
```

I hide the column of the correct answers and I use if statement on Correct/Incorrect column. And the user must input the correct spelling of each state in State Abr. Column on State Column. My problem is, the incorrect is appearing even there is no answer in State Column. How can I call the correct/incorrect if there is a answer/text on the blank space in State Column. If there is no answer the Correct/Incorrect Column must be blank.

Comment: Where are you storing the correct answers?

Comment: `=IF(B2="","",<Call_Correct/Incorrect>)`

Comment: @tigeravatar was trying to post sooner, but for some reason i got a captcha that wouldn't end before it would let me post... haven't had one of those on here in ages ='/

Comment: The correct answers are hidden in hide column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a separate `isblank` check before doing the true/false, such that:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",IF(B2=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(A2,E:E,0)),"Pass","Fail"))
```

Assumption is that there is a legend for the abreviations and their actual answers, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this sir.